# Ifelse statement in quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Anyone knows why the below ifelse throw me error in the calculated field? thank you

error from the calculated field:
ifelse({formatted_date}=formatDate(now(), ‘MM/dd/yyyy’),{Count_Days},0)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If `{Count_Days}` is a calculated field which is using the COUNT() aggregated function, then your ifelse statement will give an error due to Mismatched Aggregation.

You would need to change it to the following form instead:

```
 count(
  ifelse({formatted_date}=formatDate(now(), ‘MM/dd/yyyy’),{Days},0)
 )
```